# LINQ - double grouping with elements counting

Tags: c#, sql, linq

As example I have the following list of PlanesLogRow objects

```
public class PlanesLogRow
{
    public DateTime ArriveDate;
    public string Origin;
    public string Destination;
}
```

1. Need to get list of all of airports `(Origin + Destination).Distinct()`
2. Need to calc for every airport "arrived to airport" and "left from the airport" counts.

I need to create by one LINQ string tuple like `<airport, AsOriginCount(arrivedToCount), AsDestinationCount(LeftFromCount)>`

To get list of all of airports isn't a problem, but not sure how this can be done in case of such double grouping by different parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have list of planes you can project each plane object into two anonymous objects - one for destination, and one for origin. Then group these anonymous objects by airport and calculate totals:

```
planes.SelectMany(p => new[] { 
         new { Airport = p.origin, IsOrigin = true },
         new { Airport = p.destination, IsOrigin = false }
       })
       .GroupBy(x => x.Airport)
       .Select(g => new {
           Airport = g.Key,
           AsOriginCount = g.Count(x => x.IsOrigin),
           AsDestinationCount = g.Count(x => !x.IsOrigin)
       })
```

For given planes:

```
var planes = new List<Plane> {
    new Plane { Origin = "Minsk", Destination = "London" },
    new Plane { Origin = "Barcelona", Destination = "Minsk" },
    new Plane { Origin = "Rome", Destination = "Minsk" },
    new Plane { Origin = "Barcelona", Destination = "London" },
    new Plane { Origin = "London", Destination = "Rome" },
};
```

Output will be:

```
[
  { "Airport": "Minsk", "AsOriginCount": 1, "AsDestinationCount": 2 },
  { "Airport": "London", "AsOriginCount": 1, "AsDestinationCount": 2 },
  { "Airport": "Barcelona", "AsOriginCount": 2, "AsDestinationCount": 0 },
  { "Airport": "Rome", "AsOriginCount": 1, "AsDestinationCount": 1 }
]
```

**Update**: This query will work with Entity Framework. Generated SQL will be big and scary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're awesome!